# OpenAL Soft crashes in release mode (debug works fine)

Tags: c++, openal-soft

I have created a small sample program in C++ trying to play sounds with OpenAL Soft. The program crashes when compiled in release mode, when compiled in debug mode it works. I'm on OS X using 1.17.2.

I get this error message:

> SoundTest(28958,0x70000021d000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fbdd26062c8: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

This is the full sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Reset error state just to be sure
    alGetError();

    ALCdevice *device = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
    if (device == NULL) {
        cout << "Error creating device" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ALCcontext *context = alcCreateContext(device, NULL);
    if (!alcMakeContextCurrent(context)) {
        cout << "Failed to make context current" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ALuint buffer;

    // Set up sound buffer
    alGenBuffers((ALuint)1, &buffer);

    // Fill buffer with sine-wave
    float freq = 440.f;
    int seconds = 4;
    unsigned sample_rate = 22050;
    size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate;

    short *samples;
    samples = new short[buf_size];
    for(int i=0; i<buf_size; ++i) {
        samples[i] = (short) (32760 * sin((2.f * float(M_PI) * freq) / sample_rate * i ));
    }

    alBufferData(buffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, samples, buf_size, sample_rate);

    ALuint source;

    // Set up sound source
    alGenSources((ALuint)1, &source);
    alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, 1);
    alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, 1);
    alSource3f(source, AL_POSITION, 0, 0, 0);
    alSource3f(source, AL_VELOCITY, 0, 0, 0);
    alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_FALSE);
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);

    // Start playing
    alSourcePlay(source);

    // Wait until the sound stops playing
    ALenum state;
    do {
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state);
    } while (state == AL_PLAYING);

    // Clean up
    alDeleteSources(1, &source);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    alcDestroyContext(context);
    alcCloseDevice(device);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Offish topic: A useful tool: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html

Comment: Related: Got same issue on android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165186/openal-application-crashes-hangs-when-i-pass-non-nullptr-to-albufferdata-fro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having the same problem, have a [look at this](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/issues/43). The issue is resolved now.