# OpenAL application crashes/hangs when I pass non-nullptr to `alBufferData()` from native code

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, crash, openal

I'm trying to play some sound on Android using OpenAL and C/C++. I'm using SDL framework.

I keep getting mysterious crashes with `alBufferData()` even when my code is as simple as:

```
ALuint buf, src;
alGenBuffers(1, &buf);
alGenSources(1, &src);
uint8_t data[8000]{};
alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, data, 8000, 8000);
alSourcei(src, AL_BUFFER, buf);
alSourcePlay(src);
```

Every time the program reaches `alBufferData()` it crashes or hangs. I'm not getting any kind of error message.

Surprisingly enough, if I pass `0` instead of actual pointer to `alBufferData()`, then the program runs fine and plays some random noise.

I have absolutely no idea what's wrong.

MCVE:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>

#if !defined(ANDROID) && !defined(__ANDROID__)
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#else
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#endif

void Msg(const char *txt)
{
    SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION, "test app", txt, 0);
}
void Err(const char *txt)
{
    Msg(txt);
    std::exit(0);
}

int SDL_main(int, char **)
{
    Msg("Running build compiled at " __DATE__ " " __TIME__);

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS | SDL_INIT_VIDEO))
        Err("SDL init failed");
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
    #if !defined(ANDROID) && !defined(__ANDROID__)
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("test app", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    #else
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("test app", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN);
    #endif
    if (!win)
        Err("Window creation failed");
    SDL_GLContext con = SDL_GL_CreateContext(win);
    if (!con)
        Err("OpenGL context creation failed");
    #if !defined(ANDROID) && !defined(__ANDROID__)
    glewExperimental = 1;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        Msg("GLEW init failed");
    while (glGetError()) {}
    #endif
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    ALCdevice *device = alcOpenDevice(0);
    if (!device)
        Err("OpenAL init failed");
    const ALCint config_array[] = {ALC_FREQUENCY, 44100, ALC_MONO_SOURCES, 4, ALC_STEREO_SOURCES, 4, 0};
    ALCcontext *context = alcCreateContext(device, config_array);
    if (!context)
        Err("OpenAL context creation failed");
    if (!alcMakeContextCurrent(context))
        Err("OpenAL context switching failed");


    uint8_t sound_wave[8000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++)
    {
        float pi = std::atan(1)*4;
        sound_wave[i] = int(std::pow(std::sin(i * pi / 180 * 4),0.5) * 127) + 127;

        auto smoothstep = [](float x){return 2*x*x*x-3*x*x;};
        if (i < 1000)
            sound_wave[i] *= smoothstep(i / 1000.f);
        else if (i >= 7000)
            sound_wave[i] *= smoothstep((8000 - i) / 1000.f);
    }

    ALuint buf, src;
    int frames = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        bool click = 0;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
              case SDL_QUIT:
                std::exit(0);
                break;
              case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                click = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        switch (frames)
        {
          case 3:  Msg("Creating a buffer");   break;
          case 4:  alGenBuffers(1, &buf); if (!buf) Err("No buffer"); break;
          case 5:  Msg("Creating a source");   break;
          case 6:  alGenSources(1, &src); if (!src) Err("No source"); break;
          case 7:  Msg("Setting buffer data"); break;
          case 8:
            alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, sound_wave, 8000, 8000);
            if (int err = alGetError()) // This code is not reached
                Msg((std::string("Error code: ") + std::to_string(err)).c_str());
            break;
          case 9:  Msg("Attaching buffer");    break;
          case 10: alSourcei(src, AL_BUFFER, buf);  break;
          case 11: Msg("Done");                break;
        }
        if (frames < 12)
            frames++;

        if (frames == 12 && click)
            alSourcePlay(src);

        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(win);
    }
}
```

Here is my Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips

APP_STL := c++_shared

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := c++_shared
APP_CFLAGS += -w
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -I../lib/include
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++14 -O3 -s
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

I'm using OpenAL which was prebuilt using standalone toolchains. I don't know if it matters, but here is my build command (this one is for armv7-a, for other ABIs there are different commands):

```
cmake -D CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:string=android -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER:filepath="Y:/clang_3.8_android_api12_androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang.cmd" ^
                                          -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:filepath="Y:/clang_3.8_android_api12_androideabi/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-clang++.cmd" ^
                                          -D CMAKE_C_FLAGS:string="-w -O3 -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16" ^
                                          -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:string="-w -O3 -mthumb -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16" ^
                                          -D CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:string="-lc++_shared" ^
                                          -D CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:string="-lc++_shared" ^
                                          -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:string="Release" ^
                                          -G "MinGW Makefiles" ^
                                          ../../..
mingw32-make.exe
```

#### EDIT:

Now it's getting more interesting. I've managed to make it work once, but after a tiny unrelated change to the source code it broke again.

There MUST be some kind undefined behaviour somewhere, but I'm sure it's not on my side.

Is it a bug in OpenAL? The exact version I'm using is `openal-soft-1.17.1`.

#### EDIT:

Updated to OpenAL 1.17.2. No luck, same error.

#### EDIT:

[Here is logcat output for the mcve from the emulator.](http://pastebin.com/428EsNa3)
It's hosted externally because it's 2000+ lines long.

If I understood correctly, the log says that there is a heap corruption and that that application had sigsegv'ed in `dlmalloc()`. But I have no idea how to fix it.

I've tried to add `SDL_INIT_AUDIO` flag to `SDL_Init()` - same error.

Comment: Related: Someone got same issue on Mac OS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889119/openal-soft-crashes-in-release-mode-debug-works-fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like [a bug in OpenAL](https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/issues/43), which also affects MacOS. It should be already fixed.

Also it crashes only when the library is built in "Release" or "RelWithDebInfo" modes. Switching to any random string or "Debug" fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hello :) for me the line

```
alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO8, sound_wave, 8000, 8000);
```

should be part of the issue.
From documentation :

```
void alBufferData(
       ALuint      buffer,
       ALenum      format,
       const ALvoid *data,
       ALsizei      size,
       ALsizei      freq
      );
```

size : the size of the audio data in bytes
freq : the frequency of the audio data

My first point your freq (8000) is perhaps unsupported by implementation, try 44100 as the context frequency. You'll need to enlarge your `sound_wave` array. If it's work you'll can get the '8k' frequency effect by having the same sample value for 5/6 samples ;)

My second point is for the size, it may be better to use the type `ALubyte` from `al.h` and for the `size` something like `sizeof(sound_wave)` or `samples_count * sizeof(ALubyte)` to be sure and always match code changes.

But for documentation giving `NULL` in place of `data` will set `AL_INVALID_VALUE` error state (as `alGetError()` returns)

Hope it'll help

Comment: AL is definitely able to convert sounds between different sample rates (at least between 44100 and 48000, not sure why 8000 wouldn't work). I doubt `ALubyte` is anything but `unsigned char`, otherwise I would get an error on the pointer conversion. Most probably it was an OpenAL bug, see the bug report I linked.